# Habilitar conexion remota a base de datos oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo una base de datos en un servidor y localmente la conexión es correcta con sqldeveloper pero si intento acceder desde otra ip se queda cargando y la conexión se cae por timeout, tengo entendido que debo habilitar la conexión remota pero no encuentro documentación que me sirva y no se como habilitar dicha conexion y poder acceder a la base de datos desde otra parte, agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Y puedes entrar en la consola o cmd con sqlplus?

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te marca?

Comment: Localmente desde donde tengo la BD si, puedo entrar sin ningun problema, en realidad no marca ningun error el problema es que me intento conectar desde un sqldeveloper que tengo en otra ip dentro de la misma red en la que esta el servidor y la conexi,on arroja un tomeout

Comment: ¿Configuraste el listener?
Por el comentario del timeout, convendria que tambien revisaras los firewalls en el server y tu maquina.

Comment: Si, intente configurar el listener agregando la ip de la maquina con la cual me quiero conectar, aunque en realidad no encontre claridad de como configurar el litener para permitir conexiones remotas en 12c, en el mismo server hay un 11g y permite las conexiones remotas; en cuanto a lo otro si revise el server y la maquina en el server habilite los puertos y revise el firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Intenta realizar un **ping** desde la máquina local hacia la máquina remota. Esto para corroborar que estas en la misma red. Esta prueba en ambas direcciones.
2. Si tienes éxito del paso 1 verifica el **firewall** de la máquina remota! Si es **linux** descarta los **iptables**. De ser **Windows** descarta el **firewall** de guindos...perdón **Windows**.
3. Verifica que este corriendo perfectamente el **listener** en el servidor remoto.
4. En el **tnsname.ora** del servidor local crea el servicio del servidor remoto e intenta vía consola aplicar **tnsping** (nombre del servicio)

Prueba eso y comenta a ver que pasa

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, el error se encontraba en el archivo tnsnames,ora al parecer no reconocía el servicio, una vez configurado reinicie los servicios del oracle y problema resuelto :)